# If One Considers Chabad to be Avodah Zarah What Kosher Products Should He Avoid?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, avodah-zarah, chabad

If one were to consider Chabad to be a religion of Avodah Zarah because of their practices regarding the Rebbe as Mashiach, what otherwise marked "kosher" products should one avoid that are Chabad-made products?

Comment: Essentially the question can be boiled down to: *What are some Chabad-made products?* ?

Comment: since the chabad rebbe sent sluchim all over so they are the mashgichim all over so you may as well stop eating anything that is factory produced!

Answer (score 0):

Cuvée Chabad wines, which are produced in Napa, California, by Chabad rabbis as a fundraiser for the organization and bear the Chabad name, are most certainly a Chabad-made product.

Comment: Also the famous Bartenura "Blue Bottle"

Comment: @DoubleAA is it all Bartenura or just the blue bottle?